# How to subprocess this call in python: png2pos args > /dev/usb/lp0

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I currently have the following code:

```
subprocess.call(["png2pos", "-c", "example_2.png", ">", "/dev/usb/lp0"])
```

The program png2pos is being accessed because it's giving me the message:

> This utility produces binary sequence printer commands. Output have to
>   be redirected

This is the same error I get if I forget to type in > /dev/usb/lp0, so I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the '>' character. How would one redirect this output to /dev/usb/lp0 with subprocess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure the output is redirected properly, you need to set `shell` to `True` and pass a single string:

`subprocess.call("png2pos -c example_2.png > /dev/usb/lp0", shell=True)`

Otherwise `">"` is treated as a program argument.

Comment: there is no need to use `shell=True` here. See answers in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have your tool installed, so I cannot really test here. But had an issue with redirecting output from a console application using python before. I had to redirect it using the command itself, not via the shell (as you are trying)

```
with open("/dev/usb/lp0", 'wb') as output_str:
    subprocess.Popen(["png2pos", "-c", "example_2.png"], stdout=output_str)
```